# Finding the sum of an array Java

Tags: java

I've searched all over the place and I can't seem to find a solution to my problem. I have an array that contains how many times my random walk lands on a specified location. Now I need to find the sum of this array but for some reason the sum always gives 1000:(

```
int[] hx;
hx = new int[1000];
int hx_sum = 0;
for (int i = -500; i < 500; i++) {
   hx[i+500] = totals.get(i);
}
for(int w = 0; w < 1000; w++){
   hx_sum += hx[w];
}
System.out.print(hx_sum);
}
```

The result of my hx_sum is ALWAYS = 1000.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: what is returned by `totals.get(i)`, that's what's filling your array.

Comment: totals.get is just my hashmap and the totals.get(i) just represents all the numbers that's being put in my array. It's quite irrelevant.

Comment: No, it's not because the numbers that come out of it fill your array and those are the numbers that are summed to get your total

Comment: @user2966573 No it's relevant. Please add this informations.

Comment: The full source code is here: http://pastebin.com/Hm2Fcn8K

Comment: You don't need the hx array at all. Just sum your totals.get(i) for all valid i.

Comment: I need the hx array for later use:P

Comment: but @Ingo regardless it's still resulting in 1000

Comment: And as long as you are summing values that start at zero with exactly one of them incremented by one on each iteration of a 1000 iteration loop, that is what you will always get. If you made `NBR_WALKS` three the sum would be three.

Comment: Maybe we can get at this another way. You plan to use this total for something. What? Almost certainly, you don't want the total because it is just `NBR_WALKS`, but maybe there is some other function of the hash map that would mean what you want.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan You're probably on the right track. As it stands, the hx[] array is totally useless, as all the information is already in the Map. He surely wanted to add some information. But what?

Comment: I would say double check that `totals.get(i)` doesn't ALWAYS return 1...

Comment: There are all sorts of interesting numbers that could be derived from the hash map, such as the number of non-zero values or the mean of the non-zero values. It's just a matter of working out what the OP needs for the next step.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan what do you suggest I do? I want to have an array that contains how many times it landed on -500, -499 ...., -5,...0...5..499,500.

Comment: And then a possibility to find the sum of that.

Comment: Your current array contains the numbers of times it landed on each location just fine. You are also calculating its sum correctly, even if pointlessly. The question is what you expect the "sum" to tell you. There is probably some other statistic that can be obtained from the map or the array that would tell you what you want to know.

Answer (score 4):

You do 1000 steps (NBR_WALK), and in each step you increment one point in your hash map. The map was initialized with all 0 before.

Quick question: What is the sum of 1000 increments?

Do you see the error? It is not really an error, it is just mathematically certain that no different result is possible.

If you don't see it, I suggest you take a dice, throw it 10 times, and increment each time the array element corresponding to the number (which you can draw on paper). Initialize the array with all 0 before you start.
Then compute the sum of the array. It can only ever be 10.

This could look like:

```
Dice      1s         2s      3s     4s     5s    6s
  1      x
  5      x                                 x
  3      x                   x             x
  1      xx                  x             x
```

Now count the `x`s  in the last line. Its 4, because you were rolling the dice 4 times, and every time you added 1 `x`. Also, in each line, there is exactly one more `x` then in the preceding line. Thus, after 1000 rounds you will have 1000 x.

Comment: It's all functioning exactly like it should, but I need to be able to have my program calculate the sum of the array, all the slots added together.

Comment: Yes, @user2966573. Think about it: if - by chance - you landed always on the same spot, what would be the total for that spot? What would be the total for all other slots?

Comment: I'm sorry mate, but when I print out my totals.get(i) i get exactly what I'm looking for, I just want all these numbers added together.

Comment: Here's another way to see the issue. You initialize totals with all values 0. The only thing that changes a value is the line `totals.put(total_value, totals.get(total_value) + 1);`. You do that exactly once on each iteration of a loop. What will the total value be after one iteration? After 2 iterations? After 3 iterations? After 1000 iterations?

Comment: Still another way: Suppose the sum of all totals is `n`. Then you do 1 step and increment exactly 1 slot. What is the sum of the array now?

Comment: If you know about "mathematical induction" you can easily combine my comment and @Ingo's comment immediately before this one to get a mathematical proof that the sum must be 1000.

Comment: I think I see the problem now @Ingo what should I do :(?

Comment: I appologise, I thank you for the help, I just realised how dumb i was. Cheers